# How to get only checked contact details inside a listview and leave unchecked contacts?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, contacts

I loaded contacts into listview with checkboxes now i want to return details of only checked contacts like name and phone number.How will i get details?Where are the details stored in the listview like position,id etc.Below code is given

```
String[] from = { "Name", "Phone","chkbox" };
        int[] to = { R.id.txtContactName, R.id.txtContactNumber,R.id.checkBox1 };
        ArrayList<Map<String,String>> list=buildData();
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
                R.layout.main, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

private ArrayList<Map<String,String>> buildData() {
        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        list.clear();
        Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
        while (people.moveToNext()) {
            String contactName = people.getString(people
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String contactId = people.getString(people
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String hasPhone = people
                    .getString(people
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
            if ((Integer.parseInt(hasPhone) > 0)) {
                Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = " + contactId,
                        null,
                        "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                                + ") ASC");
                while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneNumber = phones
                            .getString(phones
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    Map<String, String> NamePhoneType = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    NamePhoneType.put("Name", contactName);
                    NamePhoneType.put("Phone", phoneNumber);
                    list.add(NamePhoneType);
                     aa=contactName;
                     bb=phoneNumber;
                }
                phones.close();
            }
        }
        people.close();
        return list;
    }


@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1); 

        if (checkbox.isChecked() == false) {
            checkbox.setChecked(true); 
           int aaa=l.getCheckedItemPosition();

        } else {
            checkbox.setChecked(false); 
        }

    }
```

xml code

Main XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="5.0px"
android:paddingLeft="5.0px"
android:paddingTop="5.0px" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtContactName"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="15.0dip"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox1"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:text="Medium Text"
android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtContactNumber"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/txtContactName"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="15.0dip"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox1"
android:text="Small Text"
android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />

<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activit_cont xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnShow"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Show Selected" />

<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/btnShow" >
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you include the xml? Also, when are you calling your `buildData` function?

Comment: I have edited my code have a look at it

Comment: Did my answer help you at all?

Comment: hey was out for a while..I tried but i didnt understand equal method u were refering...I am getting errors i have to change String name to Textview name inorder to remove error

Comment: an `equals` method is necessary for the `remove` function to work on the ArrayList. I left it for you to figure out how to implement an `equals` method for a class. Is there any way that I could help you understand my answer?

Comment: i have tried according to what u said but i am getting some errors..i have answered my code below hav a look..

Comment: check out my edit in my answer explaining some of the concepts you are having errors with! In the future, you should generally add edits to your question if you have not actually answered your question as opposed to adding an "Answer" that has more questions and errors in it.

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to recommend that you should be extending the `getView` method of the list adapter (read up on that) and, within that, doing some variation on what I will suggest, but just to get you unstuck, here is a way to incorporate this into your code. I would definitely recommend using more descriptive variable names as well :)

In the meantime:

If you want a list of all the people (and their number) that have been checked at any given point in time, it may make sense to maintain a separate instance variable that is an `ArrayList` – something like `mCheckedContacts` that gets added to as a checkbox gets checked. I would make a simply class called `ContactInformation` to put in the `ArrayList`.

```
public class ContactInformation {
  private String mName;
  private String mPhoneNumber;

  //make some getters and setters, a constructor, and an equals method!
}
```

Make sure you implement that .equals method because the code below relies upon it (see: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object) for reference). Now you can have the following `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<ContactInformation> mCheckedContactsInformation = new ArrayList<ContactInformation>();
```

This can be added to your code, and you can add and remove contacts to/from this list.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
  CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1); 
  String name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtContactName); 
  String phoneNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtContactNumber); 

  checkbox.setOnCheckedChangedListener(
    new OnCheckedChangedListener() {
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        ContactInformation curContactInfo = new ContactInformation(name, phoneNumber);
        if (isChecked) mCheckedContactsInformation.add(curContactInfo);
        //And this is why you need to implement a .equals method!
        else mCheckedContactsInformation.remove(curContactInfo);
      }
  }

  checkbox.setChecked(! checkbox.isChecked());
}
```

Now you should be able to utilize that ArrayList to get the information you need.

---

**EDIT**: Based on your own answer, it looks like you may need further explanation on some of these topics.

**Classes**: A class *must* have a constructor. A constructor is the way you instantiate an object. Whenever you make a call like this:

```
Object o = new Object(int thisCouldBeAnyTypeOfParameter);
```

you are calling the method within `Object`'s class that looks like this:

```
public Object(int thisCouldBeAnyTypeOfParameter) {
  //here is some initialization code that someone wrote, or nothing...
  //but this method NEEDS to exist!

  //And if a parameter is passed, like the int above, then it is probably used to init something
}
```

for more info (and likely a better explanation) [check out this info, straight from the source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html). So, when you get this error:

> The constructor ContactInformation(String, String) is undefined

This occurs likely on the line:

```
ContactInformation curContactInfo = new ContactInformation(name, phoneNumber);
```

Why? *Because you have not created a constructor in the class that takes in two Strings*. The error you got is actually pretty much exactly the problem that is occurring. I would recommend that you google these kinds of errors and spend time reading the results you find. Unfortunately this stuff takes time to learn, and while there are people who will help you, most of the work will have to be done by *you* simply spending hours and hours reading and coding, reading and coding.

The next error that you are getting:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from TextView to String

Think about the line of code that this is occurring:

```
String name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtContactName);
```

The left hand side is a String, and expects a String to be returned. On the right hand side, you are not returning a String. For this kind of problem, it is helpful to look at the Android documentation. For example, the `findViewById()` function... what does it return? You are casting the resulting type (which is a `View`) to a `TextView` which is an Object of type `TextView`. This is not a String therefore you are getting an error because you are trying to assign a `TextView` object to a `String`. It makes sense that this would not work because they are different types. In this case you need to do a little bit of extra work to get the String (stored in the TextView object) out of the object so you can assign it to a String. I'll leave this extra work for you to determine, but do a google search for "textview android", click on the first link, and look at all of the methods that can be called on a TextView. I bet you will find one that returns the String :)

Hope this helps. Sorry to be so long winded/didactic, but I'm just trying to help.

Answer (score -1):

```
        String[] from = { "Name", "Phone","chkbox" };
        int[] to = { R.id.txtContactName, R.id.txtContactNumber,R.id.checkBox1 };
        ArrayList<Map<String,String>> list=buildData();
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
                R.layout.main, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);




    }

    private ArrayList<Map<String,String>> buildData() {
        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        list.clear();
        Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
        while (people.moveToNext()) {
            String contactName = people.getString(people
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String contactId = people.getString(people
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String hasPhone = people
                    .getString(people
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
            if ((Integer.parseInt(hasPhone) > 0)) {
                Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = " + contactId,
                        null,
                        "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                                + ") ASC");
                while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneNumber = phones
                            .getString(phones
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    Map<String, String> NamePhoneType = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    NamePhoneType.put("Name", contactName);
                    NamePhoneType.put("Phone", phoneNumber);
                    list.add(NamePhoneType);
                    aa=contactName;
                     bb=phoneNumber;
                }
                phones.close();
            }
        }
        people.close();
        return list;
    }

    ArrayList<ContactInformation> mCheckedContactsInformation = new ArrayList<ContactInformation>();

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1); 
        // String name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtContactName);
        TextView tvv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtContactName);
        TextView tvv2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtContactNumber);
        final String name=tvv1.getText().toString();
        final String phoneNumber=tvv2.getText().toString();

checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    ContactInformation curContactInfo = new ContactInformation(name, phoneNumber);
    if (isChecked) mCheckedContactsInformation.add(curContactInfo);
    //And this is why you need to implement a .equals method!
    else mCheckedContactsInformation.remove(curContactInfo);

}
});
```

Contactinformation class code

```
private String name;
private String phoneNo;
//private boolean selected;

public String getName() {
    return name;

}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
     //selected = false;
}
public String getPhoneNo() {
    return phoneNo;
}
public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
    this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
}

/*public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
  }

  public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
  }*/
```

Here i am getting the error -The constructor ContactInformation(String, String) is undefined..also when i use `String name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtContactName);`
i am getting the error -Type mismatch: cannot convert from TextView to String...Also can i use the boolean selected method which i have commented instead of ur suggested .equals method??